# How do I save the output in the nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a short python web scraping script for my assignment.  I was successfully able to print the items, but I am unable to save my output in the desired format.

Here is HTML snippet. Full link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M)

```
<td style="width:11%; vertical-align:top;">
<p><b>M5A</b><br/>
<span style="font-size:80%;">
<a href="/wiki/Downtown_Toronto" title="Downtown Toronto">Downtown Toronto</a>
<br/>
(<a href="/wiki/Regent_Park" title="Regent Park">Regent Park</a> / 
<a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Harbourfront,_Toronto" title="Harbourfront, Toronto">Harbourfront</a>)
</span>
</p>
</td>
```

Here is my script

```
for i, element in enumerate(table_lines):
    lst =[]
    span = table_lines[i].find('span')
    if span.text != 'Not assigned':
        print(element.find('b').text)
        neighborhoods = element.findAll('a')
        for i, link in enumerate(neighborhoods):
            if i == 0:
                print("city:",link.text)
            else:
                print("areas", link.text)
        print('----------------')
```

My desired output format

```
{'postcode': 'M5A', 'city': 'Downtown Toronto', 'areas': 'Regent Park, Harbourfront' }
```

Comment: Have you tried using an HTML parser library?

Comment: Hey, Mike!
Perpaps it'd help if you showed the context of the ```table_lines``` or else what your output looks like right now so we could help.

Comment: I updated question with the link. I am currently just printing the output in console not sure how to store it. sorry I am completely beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you did the difficult part, find the correct nodes and the value, plus the logic. The part of adding to a list of objects is pretty simple compare to that.

Here is an example I think it should work, I just change the print for the corresponding var assign, and then create the object and push it to the final list.

```
lst =[]
for i, element in enumerate(table_lines):
    span = table_lines[i].find('span')
    if span.text != 'Not assigned':
        postcode = element.find('b').text
        neighborhoods = element.findAll('a')
        areas = []
        for i, link in enumerate(neighborhoods):
            if i == 0:
                city = link.test
            else:
                areas.append(link.test)
        lst.append({
            'postcode': postcode,
            'city': city,
            'areas': ','.join(areas)
        })
print(lst)
```

BTW, the result should a list of the one you mention, one object for each row.